# print characters between a specific pattern containing <>

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i am asking for your help please.

I reviewed a lot of sources and did some testing with awk and sed, but i can't get it to work. Below is a snippet of a config file which i could get an output via grep, but not the way i need it.

```
> file.txt
> 
> "<property>name="DBName"><value>ABC</value>name="DBName"><value>DEF</value></property>
> 
> cat file.xml | grep -o -P '.name="DBName"><value>.{0,20}'
> name="DBName"><value>ABC</value>
> name="DBName"><value>DEF</value></propert
```

The desired output is:

```
ABC
DEF
```

Thanks for any help.

Andi

Comment: Welcome, please [edit] the question, specifically the code part. Remove the trailing `> ` and add the relevant snippets of the file `file.xml` apart of the `grep` command. The best approach for XML files generally is to use tools designed for parsing that format like `xmllint` (approach valid for other structured formats like JSON).

Comment: If your data is actual XML, looks like `<` are missing before both `name=`. Can you, please, clarify ? Apart from this, you don't need to `cat someFile | grep [options]`, you can directly `grep [options] someFile`.

Comment: You show the content of `files.txt` but then your code cats `file.xml` and your file.txt has lines in double quotes but missing some `<`s, etc. Please clean up your question to clearly show us the actual input you need help parsing. I suspect you have a file.xml which you're doing some pre-processing on to create file.txt and are now asking for help to do further processing on - don't do that as it's unlikely to be the best approach, just show the contents of `file.xml` and the desired final output.

Comment: Try this: grep -oP '\>[A-Za-z0-9]+\<' infile | tr -d '\<\>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (huge, enormous "if") your file really only has the very simple case where you want the *exact* string `<value>` followed by a few non-`<` characters and then `</value>`, so your problem can be formuated as "fetch me the string of simple, non-newline characters found between each occurrence of `<value>` and the first `<` after it", then you can do (using GNU `grep`):

```
grep -oP '<value>\K[^<]+' file
```

Of course, this will fail on anything even slightly different. If you have multi-line values, for example, or if the value tag can have something like `<value foo=bar>` or on any number of other, perfectly valid XML cases. The Right Way© is to use an XM: parser instead. You might want to check out [`xmllint`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) or [XMLStarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) among others.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your input looks exactly like the one line of sample input you posted:

```
$ cat file
"<property>name="DBName"><value>ABC</value>name="DBName"><value>DEF</value></property>
```

then using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'[<>]+' '{for (i=5; i<=NF; i+=4) print $i}' file
ABC
DEF
```

but, like any other solution that doesn't use an XML parser, that is fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Using `XMLStarlet`:

XML file taken from [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/765369/469418).

```
<config>
 <property name="DBName"><value>ABC</value></property>
 <property name="DBName" year="2023"><value>DEF</value></property>
 <property name="SystemName"><value>s70</value></property>
</config>
```

```
$ xmlstarlet select -t -v '//value' --nl ex.xml
ABC
DEF
s70

$ xmlstarlet select -t -m '//property[@name="DBName"]' -v 'value' --nl ex.xml
ABC
DEF
```

---

Using awk:

```
$ awk -v pat1="<value>" -v pat2="</value>" '
   {
       while (match($0, pat1)){ 
           $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);
           if (match($0, pat2)) print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
       }
   }
'
```

The `awk` and `pcregrep` solutions work for this question but may fail on many occasions.

```
$ pcregrep -o1 '<value>(.*?)</value>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot, this worked for me. Here to sum it up more sample code and the final solution for mr:

```
host123:~ # grep -oP '.{0,50}name="DBName"><value>.{0,100}' file.xml
ystemName"><value>XYZ</value></property><property name="DBName"><value>ABC-SERVER1</value></property><property name="SystemHome"><value>host123</value></property><prope 
ystemName"><value>XYZ</value></property><property name="DBName"><value>DEF</value></property><property name="SystemHome"><value>host123</value></property><property name=


host123:~ # grep -oP 'name="DBName"><value>\K[^<]+' file.xml 
ABC-SERVER1 
DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a well formed XML input such us

```
<config>
 <property name="DBName"><value>ABC</value></property>
 <property name="DBName" year="2023"><value>DEF</value></property>
 <property name="SystemName"><value>s70</value></property>
</config>
```

You can use a XML-aware tool, and use Xpath (or similar) to select the
parts to extract. Example with **xidel**:

```
## 1) get all values:
$ xidel -e "//value" ex.xml 
ABC
DEF
s70
## 2) get the values inside "property" with attribute "name" "DBname"
$ xidel -e "//property[@name='DBname']/value" ex.xml 
ABC
DEF
```