# print a text block / lines between pattern using grep or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

My file `file.txt` looks like this:

```ini
[NamesA]
Andreas
Alex

[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno

[NamesC]
Casper

[NamesD]
Doris
```

I would like accomplish the following 3 different outputs, using `grep` or `awk` to use it in a bash script:

1. Output

   ```ini
   [NamesB]   
   Bernd   
   Bruno
   ```
2. Output

   ```ini
   [NamesB]
   Bernd
   Bruno

   [NamesC] 
   Casper
   ```
3. Output

   ```ini
   [NamesD]
   Doris
   ```

I tried:

```shell
grep  -oP '\[NamesB\].*?' file.txt
```

but get only `[NamesB]` and not the following textblock. I managed to get text which is direct behind, but not in a new line.

And that's it. If I would get at least all following lines starting with `[NamesB]`, but even this did not work.

- So I can imagine the output for 1. might be the simplest by printing all starting with `[NamesB]` and ending at the next `[`.
- I also can imagine how this might work for 2.
  Similar to output 1. but then running `grep` 2 times. One time with `[NamesB]` and then with `[NamesC]`

But how would this then work for 3. as there is no `[` next. And it could be possible there is an unknown next block starting with `[`.

The command should then start printing text starting with `[NamesB]` or whatever and then stop either with the next opening bracket `[` or by the end of the file.

PS: I posted a smilar question already and found a solution, but it was [all one line of text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765304/print-characters-between-a-specific-pattern-containing). In this question i have a different situation of a text block and not a single line.

Comment: It's totally not clear why `NamesB`is output twice, and the `2. Output` contains two `Names` groups. Anyways, nope, that's not something that line-based `grep` can do for you. You need to learn a scripting language and use that. Maybe you even already know one? Python? Go? awk? Perl? JavaScript?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure you show us accurate files. Is the first line of your file actually `file.txt`? If not, please remove it. Do you really want the strings `1. Output`, `2. Output` etc in your output? And why is output repeated? Please show us the _exact_ input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements for selecting which record(s) to print aren't clear but maybe this is what you're trying to do, using any awk:

Output 1, option 1 (read 1 line at a time):

```
$ awk '/^\[/{f=(/^\[NamesB]/)} f' file.txt
[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno
```

Output 1, option 2 (read 1 multi-line record at a time)

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$1 == "[NamesB]"' file.txt
[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno
```

Output 2, option 1 (print the NamesB record and whichever record comes after it):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$1 == "[NamesB]"{c=2} c&&c--' file.txt
[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno

[NamesC]
Casper
```

Output 2, option 2 (print the NamesB and NamesC records, wherever they are in the input):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$1 ~ /^\[Names[BC]]$/' file.txt
[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno

[NamesC]
Casper
```

Output 3, option 1 (print the NamesD record):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$1 == "[NamesD]"' file.txt
[NamesD]
Doris
```

Output 3, option 2 (print the 4th record from the input, whatever Name it has):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' 'NR == 4' file.txt
[NamesD]
Doris
```

Also, regarding:

> If I would get at least all following lines starting with [NamesB]

the following would do that:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$1 == "[NamesB]"{f=1} f' file.txt
[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno

[NamesC]
Casper

[NamesD]
Doris
```

There are, of course, many other scripts that could be written to produce that output based on various criteria, the right one will depend on whatever your requirements are for selecting the block(s) to output.

Answer (score 1):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'for slurp.split("\n\n") { .put if / \[ NamesA \]  /};'   file

#OR

~$ raku -e '.put if / \[ NamesA \]  / for slurp.split("\n\n");'   file
```

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, the file is `slurp`ed into memory all at once, and `split` on `\n\n` two consecutive newlines. Resultant elements (records) are iterated through using `for`: `if` a match is found to the desired regex, the element (record) is out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
[NamesA]
Andreas
Alex

[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno

[NamesC]
Casper

[NamesD]
Doris
```

Sample Output:

```
[NamesA]
Andreas
Alex
```

Note, you can return multiple records by using an `|` OR symbol within the regex matcher. To properly separate the return, the `$_.put` or `.put` portion can be re-written as `put "$_\n"` to pad each record with a trailing newline:

```
~$ raku -e 'put "$_\n" if / \[ NamesA | NamesB \]  / for slurp.split("\n\n");'   file
[NamesA]
Andreas
Alex

[NamesB]
Bernd
Bruno
```

Note: the regex matcher can be to any line within the record. To match specifically to the first line use `/^ \[ NamesA \] $$ /`, where `^` denotes beginning-of-string and `$$` denotes end-of-line.

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

You can extract any of the blocks (e.g. NamesA) with this command:

```
$ awk '/^\[NamesA/{p=1; print; next} /^\[/{p=0}; p>0{print}' input_file
[NamesA]
Andreas
Alex
```

The [ as first character of block headers needs to be escaped as shown in the code.

Using this one-liner you can print any combination of outputs to suit your needs.

Comment: Or more simply with a range pattern: `awk '/^\[NamesA/,/^$/' file` (omitted action = default to `print $0`) (may need `/^[:blank:]*$/` or similar if visibly-empty lines are not really empty). sed can do the same: `sed -n '/^\[NamesA/,/^$/p' file`

Comment: You assume that blank lines are delimiters. If a line looks blank but actually has invisible white spaces then your version fails. Therefore it is safer to assume that the header lines are block delimiters and any 'blank' lines belong to the preceding block.

Comment: That's exactly why I said `/^[:blank:]*$/`. But both your any my versions fail if the `[NamesA]` line contains LRM ZWJ ZWNJ or similar (including BOM mostly on Windows) -- or if the apparent `[NamesA]` is really RLM `]AsemaN[`.